# nfa of the Language L={w belongs to (a,b)*/w starts with aa or ends with aa} with or being not exclusive

Tags: formal-languages, automata, finite-automata

I have a question I need to give the NFA of the following language: L={w belongs to (a,b)*/w starts with aa or ends with aa}  with or being not exclusive meaning I can have a word that starts with aa and ends with aa.
I did this:
[image]

but if I turn it into the DFA I get this:
[image]

but with this DFA if we have the word "baab" it ends in an accepted state which is wrong.
can anyone please help me know where my mistake is.

---

Update:
I did starts with aa as DFA and end with aa as DFA I did the union I got the DFA.
if I wanted the NFA should I do D1 and D2 as NFA instead of DFA?
[image]

Comment: Your NFA effectively checks whether there are two consecutive $a$s at any point in the input word.

Answer (score 0):

The incorrect behavior of the DFA comes from the fact that NFA is also wrong.
Look at the initial state: it contains a self-transition labelled $b$. You are effectively "discarding" all leading $b$s.
Instead, your NFA/DFA needs to check whether a word starts with $aa$ and "remember" it (via new states).

Probably the easiest way to solve this exercise is that of building a DFA $D_1$ for strings that start with $aa$ and another DFA $D_2$ for strings that end with $aa$. Designing $D_1$ and $D_2$ should be trivial. Finally, combine $D_1$ and $D_2$ into a NFA by adding a new initial state and two $\epsilon$-transitions.

Comment: but isn't what I wrote like if it starts with b just stay in your place since we do not care about the bs and then if it receive an a it moves to the next state arriving at q2 where it means it ends with aa and if b arrive again and the string didn't start with aa it goes back to the initial state